# How to pass images from enum with multiple property to UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I made Quiz app "What Pokemon are you", where on the last screen shows  what a Pokemon are you and description! I want to add  image for each Pokemon. How can I do this via switch?

```
enum PokemonType {
    case Pikachy
    case Sloupok
    case Vaperon
    case Lucario
    case Slugma




    var definition: String {
        switch self {
        case .Pikachy:
            return "some text"
        case .Sloupok:
             return "some text"
        case .Vaperon:
            return "some text"
        case .Lucario:
            return "some text"
        case .Slugma:
            return "some text"

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly you want to achieve and what you have tried.

Comment: sorry , i can't understand what is your correct problem is..

Comment: var images:UIImage { return } ?

Comment: I want to add property for enum PokemonType, so that at the end of the Quiz, appear not only the name of the Pakrmon and description, but also the image

Answer (score 1):

Same way you added definition, add another property called image

```
enum pokemonType {
    case pikachy
    case sloupok
    case vaperon
    case lucario
    case slugma

    var definition: String {
        switch self {
        case .pikachy:
            return "some text"
        case .sloupok:
             return "some text"
        case .vaperon:
            return "some text"
        case .lucario:
            return "some text"
        case .slugma:
            return "some text"

     }

     var image: UIImage {
        switch self {
        case .pikachy:
            return UIImage(named: "any_image_name")
        case .sloupok:
             return UIImage(named: "any_image_name")
        case .vaperon:
            return UIImage(named: "any_image_name")
        case .lucario:
            return UIImage(named: "any_image_name")
        case .slugma:
            return UIImage(named: "any_image_name")

     }
   }
}
```